# How user regex to have one or more uppercase letter separated by comma?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need validate a input using regex (i think it's better) but in this input can be one or more "sentences" and be [A-Z] size 1. How can i do that?
E.g.:
`A,B,D,G,J,X` no repeat letters but this validate i do in code. I think regex is better 'cause validate a entire sentence instead letter by letter using a loop and split. My english is rusty, appreciate some help to improve =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note,  Assumption is you want a single letter

If you just want to validate:

```
    if (/([A-Z]*)?,([A-Z]*),?/.test(subject)) {
        // Successful match
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    }
```

If you are using to get extract values:

```
 result = subject.match(/([A-Z]*)?,([A-Z]*),?/g);
```

Comment: Thanks, have a delicious day!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you `([A-Z],)+[A-Z]` it will match a serie of uppercase letter followed by comma, and end with uppercase letter :

## regex demo

---

```
A,B,D,G,J,X      -> matches
A,B,DE,G,J,X     -> not matches
A,B,D,G,J,XY     -> not matches
```

Comment: Thank you!! I used `console.log(new RegExp(/^([A-Z],)+[A-Z]$/g).test($(this).val()));` to try. Have a delicious day!

Comment: you are welcome @LuanDR :)